# Deploy a Report Builder report automatically

Tags: reporting-services

I have created a report in Report Builder (*.rdl).

I know that I can deploy that report in SSRS on the test server with transfering the report to that server and import the report by using SSRS.

But, I wan't to deploy the report automatically without starting the SSRS.
Is that possible?

The RDL file is just an XML file so maybe there is a way to deploy that report automatically. The ultimate way for me to deploy a report is to deploy it when commiting the report to git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Visual Studio to deploy your reports. Or you can use a powershell script from here https://github.com/Microsoft/ReportingServicesTools/.